# Issue with dynamic css ( transform: translateY(30px) !important )

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, css-selectors, angular-material

enter link description here

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE3o1.png][ Defect image is here, I am trying to create a side menu]

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kk3ikj?file=src/app/app.component.html][ Here is the source code]

```
When I see the screen with **Page Ruler Redux** extension in chrome,
With that extension, Html code is overload transform CSS dynamically, 
How to resolve this issue
side menu.html
========================
<ul *ngFor="let route of routes">
  <li *ngIf="true" routerLinkActive="active" >
    <a (click)="menuItemClick(route)"> {{route.displayText}}
      <!-- <i [class]="[getRouteIcon(route)]"></i> -->
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
Side Menu.css
==============
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #002b3f;
    }

    li {
      color: #c9c9c9;
      padding: 8px 16px;
    }

  li:hover {
      color: #007dba;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, I didn't abuse the code block, I thought because of it ( transform: translateY(30px) !important ) happens the issue, when I open the screen with page ruler redux extension this CSS overriding my HTML code

Comment: Paulie_D, In the above source code link is there you can see, Try to open in new window, Then with page ruler redux extension enable it side menu color is off, if you disable it looks normal, You can able see the difference